# Mssql procedure doesn't return records

Tags: sql-server, procedure

I wrote simply procedure, that should return some data. 
When I simply replace execute query and put `SELECT 1` It is returning `1`. But when i paste `EXECUTE` query, it is return nothing. 
What should I do?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PTC_Repor] 
    @camp       VARCHAR(50),
    @StartTime  DATETIME,
    @EndTime    DATETIME    
AS
BEGIN

    EXECUTE('
    SELECT      ID,NAME
    FROM        [hpsdb].[dbo]. [' + @camp + ']
    WHERE       IS_CLEAR = 0
    AND     SUCCESS_COUNT = 0 
    AND     DATA_STATUS = 5
    AND     CALL_TIME > ''' + @StartTime + '''
    AND     CALL_TIME <= ''' + @EndTime + '''
 ')

END
GO
```

Comment: Have you tried to execute your procedure wihtout the Execute Statement and specifying the table in the request ?

Comment: The procedure must return error `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try using [`sp_executesql`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) so that you can pass the datetime values across directly and not force them to become strings:

```
declare @Parms nvarchar(max)
set @Parms = '@StartTime datetime, @EndTime datetime'
declare @SQL nvarchar(max)
set @SQL = 'SELECT      ID,NAME
  FROM        [hpsdb].[dbo]. [' + @camp + ']
  WHERE       IS_CLEAR = 0
  AND     SUCCESS_COUNT = 0 
  AND     DATA_STATUS = 5
  AND     CALL_TIME > @StartTime
  AND     CALL_TIME <= @EndTime'

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,@Prams,@StartTime,@EndTime
```